# I have links I want to count the number of times each link is clicked by and save this counting in database using asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have links I want to count the number of times each link is clicked by and save this counting in database using asp.net mvc5

**this is my View**

```
 @model IEnumerable<RssFeedBackEnd.New>
 @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Show";
  }
  <h2>Show</h2>
  *@foreach (var item in Model)
  {
        <h3 dir="rtl" align="right">
            <a href="@item.LinkNews" target="_blank">@item.TitleNews</a>
        </h3>
        <h5 dir="rtl" align="right"> @item.Description</h5>
        <p dir="rtl" align="right">
        <a href="@item.LinkPage" target="kk">@item.TitlePage</a>
        </p>
         <br />
    }
```

**and this my Model**

```
public class New
{
    [Key]
    public string IDurl { get; set; }
    public int ClickCount { get; set; }
}
```

**and this my Controller**

```
public class ShowController : Controller
{
    private RssFeedDB db = new RssFeedDB();
    // GET: Show
    public ActionResult Show()
    {
        var nw = db.News;
        return View(nw);
    }}
```

I am still a beginner as you can see
I wish you help me
I am still a beginner as you can see
To find a solution to my problem

Comment: Do you specifically want to track when the *link is clicked*, or do you actually want to track when the *target page is requested*?  That is, is the target page something in your application, or could it be anything?  (Like search engine results?)  If the latter then you'll likely want to take a similar approach to what Google does and wrap the links in pass-thru pages which track the request before redirecting to the actual target.

Comment: Yes I want to specifically track when the user clicks on the link

Comment: Sorry I could not find the solution

Comment: @RahulSharma No it did not work Thanks for your help and effort

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in one of my projects, adding an 'onclick' attribute with the function I want to use, sort of:

```
<a href="@item.LinkPage" target="kk" onclick="updateItemCount(@item.IDUrl)">@item.TitlePage</a>
```

Then in JavaScript I define that function:

```
function updateItemCount(idUrl) {
     //call controller action with jQuery ajax
     $.ajax({
          url: 'urlToController',
          data: { id: idUrl }
     })
}
```

You'll need to have defined a controller action which updates your click count

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you can use AJAX to send your `idUrl` to your `Controller` method that will process your requirement. I will start with the `View` part first:

```
 @model IEnumerable<RssFeedBackEnd.New>
 @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Show";
  }
  <h2>Show</h2>
  *@foreach (var item in Model)
  {
        <h3 dir="rtl" align="right">
            <a href="@item.LinkNews" target="_blank" onclick="updateLinkCount(@item.IDurl)">@item.TitleNews</a>
        </h3>
        <h5 dir="rtl" align="right"> @item.Description</h5>
        <p dir="rtl" align="right">
        <a href="@item.LinkPage" target="kk" onclick="updateLinkCount(@item.IDurl)">@item.TitlePage</a>
        </p>
         <br />
    }

<script>
 function updateLinkCount(IDurl) {

  //Now generate your JSON data here to be sent to the server
  var json = {
              idUrl: IDurl
             };

   //Send the JSON data via AJAX to your Controller method
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ProcessMyURLCount", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json)},
        success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                  console.log("Successfully incremented count");
                 }
                else {
                 console.log("Could not increment count");
                }
        },
        error: function (error) {
             console.log(error)
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

And your `Controller` method would look like:

```
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
    public ActionResult ProcessMyURLCount(string json)
    {
        try
        {
           var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

            //Get your variables here from AJAX call
            int getid= Convert.ToInt32(jsondata["idUrl"]);

            if(getid > 0)
            {
                bool result = IncrementCountForURL(getid);

                if(result==true)
                {
                    return Json(new{success = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new{success = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }                  
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new{success = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new{success = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

And your method to increment will look like:

```
    public bool IncrementCountForURL(int idUrl)
    {
        bool flg=false;
        try
        { 
            //This is my DB class to manage my context. You would need to handle it according to your DB context
            using (DBManager db = new DBManager())
            {
                    string Query = "UPDATE {yourTable} SET urlcount=urlcount+1 WHERE idUrl=@idUrl";
                    db.Open();
                    db.CreateParameters(1);
                    db.AddParameters(0, "@idUrl", idUrl);
                    int i = db.ExecuteNonQuery (CommandType.Text, Query);
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        flg = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       flg=false;
                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         //Handle your exception
         flg=false;
        }
        return flg;
    }
```

I hope this would help you achieve your functionality. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with and works well

```
// GET: Links/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    New newss = db.News.Find(id);

    if (newss == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }


    int urlid = newss.ID;


    if (Session["URLHistory"] != null)
    {
        List<int> HistoryURLs = (List<int>)Session["URLHistory"];

        if (HistoryURLs.Exists((element => element == urlid)))
        {
            int i = newss.ClickCount;
            newss.ClickCount = i + 0;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        else
        {
            HistoryURLs.Add(urlid);
            Session["URLHistory"] = HistoryURLs;
            int i = newss.ClickCount;
            newss.ClickCount = i + 1;
            db.SaveChanges();

        }

    }
    else
    {

        List<int> HistoryURLs = new List<int>();

        HistoryURLs.Add(urlid);

        Session["URLHistory"] = HistoryURLs;

        int i = newss.ClickCount;
        newss.ClickCount = i + 1;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(newss);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What the user does on the client side, is largely out of your ability to affect. You can request that the browser tells you of clicks via JavaScript - but that is only a request. Short of programm flow (redirecting him to the Login page on every request), you do not even have a way to force the user to log in.

The closest reliable thing I can think off would be to have all links point to a page that counts the stuff, then redirects to the actuall URL (wich would be used for all further requests).

But this is the area of User Tracking (and I hope only the Subarea of [Web Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics)), wich is it's own little area. I have no experience of this area. But I did find a proper StackOverflow tag, added it and hope someone with more knowledge can help you.